# pre cache in service worker

Tags: service-worker, sw-precache

Is is correct to have this kind of path in precaching?
Ive tried to change into this but still not working

```
const PRECACHE_ASSETS = [
    `/Content/js/application/web.home.index.js`,
    `/Areas/Web/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`,
];
```

```
const CACHE_NAME = 'my-cache';

 //Add whichever assets you want to pre-cache here:
const pages = ['Home/Index', 'Careers/Index', 'Careers/Opening', 'Success/Index'];
const jsFiles = pages.map(page => `/Content/js/application/web.${page.toLowerCase()}.js`);
const cssFiles = pages.map(page => `/Content/css/application/web.${page.toLowerCase()}.css`);
const htmlFiles = pages.map(page => `/Web/Views/${page}.cshtml`);

const PRECACHE_ASSETS = [
    ...htmlFiles,
    ...jsFiles,
    ...cssFiles,
];

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    event.waitUntil((async () => {
        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        cache.addAll(PRECACHE_ASSETS);
    })());
});
```